# How to use axios interceptors in ES6 generators?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios, redux-saga

Currently, I have this Axios call, what I want to achieve is use interceptors inside ES6 generators.

I want to use axios interceptors to retry a request if the back end service sends back a "401" response, any suggestion?

```
const token = '...';

export function* getUsers(user) {
  return yield axios({
    headers: {
      Accept: "Aplication/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    method: "get",
    url: '/getUsers/:id'
 })
  .then(data => data)
  .catch(e => e)
 }
```

Comment: Is using `yeild` must for you?

Comment: Yes @nicholasnet, as I'm using redux-saga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try something like this.

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getClient = (token) => {
    const options = {};
    if (token !== null) {
        options.headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` };
    }

    const instance = axios.create(options);
    instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => response, (error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
            window.location = '/logout'; // Or whatever you want to do
        }
    
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
    
    return instance;
};

export function* getUsers(user) {

    return yield getClient('JTW_TOKEN').get('/getUsers/:id').then(data => data).catch(e => e)
}
```

Personally I prefer to have separate method for get/post/delete/put/patch etc but its not must by any means.